# if/else inside listview and formview, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, if-statement

i have a database of "Albums" and i've showed them to client via listview and formview (in 2 separate pages ):

```
<asp:ListView ID="Albums_List" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" ItemType="Trying.Models.Album" SelectMethod="GetAlbum">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%#:(Item.price == 0) ? "It's Free!" : String.Format("Price: {0:c}", Item.price)%><br />
         Artist:<%#:" " + Item.artist %><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

as you can see, i've used ternary operator to show "It's Free" if price = 0 and show the price itself if it's not 0.

now i want to show the "It's Free" in a (for example) div and red color.

here is a "scheme" of what i'm eager to do (plz note it's not really c# code):

```
<% if (Item.price == 0) { %>
    <div style="color: red;">It's Free</div>
<% } 
else { %>
    String.Format(" {0:c}", Item.price)
<% } %>
```

unfortunately, the code above is not working. to access the "Item.price", i must use <%#: %> instead of <% %>. but if i do that, i can't use the "if/else" !. besides, String.Format() is not working in this "scheme".

how to do this?

Comment: if i use the "scheme" above (without string.format() for now), i get this: the name "Item" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: if i use <%: %>, besides the error i mentioned above, i get this one too: Invalid expression term "if"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" visible='<%# Item.price == 0 %>'>
           <div style="color: red;">It's Free</div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" visible='<%# Item.price > 0 %>'>
         <%# String.Format(" {0:c}", Item.price) %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```